# Testing a secure spring mvc restful webservice

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-test

I have a secure web service that I have been trying to test. The service looks something like this:

```
@GetMapping(value= {"/v1/getSomeStuff"})
public SomeResp getSomeStuff(final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token, @RequestParam(name="searchString", required=true) String request) {
    //do some stuff in here
}
```

The services are secured using Spring Security and I am trying to write an IT test, that will supply the required UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken. I have tried doing this:

```
@Test
@Sql(scripts = { "/db-scripts/company-script.sql","/db-scripts/user-script.sql" })
@WithUserDetails(value="testuser")
public void testGetSomeStuff() {
    //test some stuff
    getRestTemplate().getForEntity("http://localhost:" + port + "/v1/getSomeStuff?searchString=foo", SomeResp.class);
}
```

The Sql scripts are executing correctly and the User Details Service is being called, but the token is not being passed to the service. I understand (now) that @WithUserDetails is for test method security and won't do what I want. My question then is, is there another method for testing secured web services using the various spring test classes?